# To refresh a report chart using REST API

Tags: visualforce, analytics-reportchart

I have created a report chart in VF page, Instead of using this refresh button(`showRefreshButton="true"`), can I refresh this report chart using REST API

```
<apex:page>    
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O2w000006idAJEAY" showRefreshButton="true" size="tiny" hideOnError="true"/>    
</apex:page>
```

Anyone have any idea? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you're trying to use REST API, when the VF component already gives you the ability to refresh?

Comment: No specific reason sir, I have heard that REST API can be used to refresh report chart. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you'd use that and the Analytics REST API if you were using the REST API and an external visualization lib already. This doesn't seem useful if you're already using the VF analytics chart component. Under the covers, I'd expect this chart component already uses the Analytics REST API, so you're probably using it implicitly.